# How do I obtain the trajectory of a particle in the plane using Newton's law of gravitation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

## Problem:

Suppose we have a fixed planet $A$ exerting gravitational force and a particle $B$:

> [image]

I want to obtain the function that gives the trajectory of $B$ to $A$. If $B$ has no velocity and no acceleration, the problem is easy. But if $B$ has some velocity into a certain direction, we could have:

> [image]

Or (I guess) something like:

> [image]

Where it could slingshot indefinitely in the planet or go away forever.

> **Question:** How do I obtain the functions that describe the trajectory of the particle?

---

## What I have tried:

Given a particle in two dimensional space, I guess I should use:

$$f=m_1(a_x,a_y)$$

And integrating twice, I obtain:

$$r(t)=m_1(a_x,a_y)\frac{t^2}{2}+(v_{x_0},v_{y_0})t+(r_{x_0},r_{y_0})$$

But suppose I want to see what happens to this particle when there is the presence of a planet on coordinates $(a,b)$, what do I do? I think it has something to do with

$$F = G \frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2}$$

But I am confused as to how I should plug it in the previous formula. I think $F$ would have a two dimensional form, like:

$$F=\left( \frac{Gm_1m_2}{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 } \right) \left(1,1 \right) \textbf{ or } F=Gm_1m_2\left(\frac{1}{(x-a)^2},\frac{1}{(y-b)^2} \right) \text{?}$$

Thinking this way, it seemed that I'd need to integrate $f+F$ but this would give me a "weird" result, when integrated, $F$ would be like:

$$F=\left( \frac{Gm_1m_2 }{((x-a)^2+(y-b)^2) } \right) \left(1,1 \right)\frac{t^2}{2} \textbf{ or } F=Gm_1m_2\left(\frac{1}{(x-a)^2},\frac{1}{(y-b)^2} \right)\frac{t^2}{2} \text{?}$$

But this seems to mean that to compute the trajectory, I'd have to use an awkward recursive process to compute the coordinates at each certain measure of time plus, the speed would increase with time. I guess that doesn't make sense.

Noticing that, I conjectured that $f$ is some kind of "object force" (Ie: What would happen to the object) and $F$ must be some kind of "field force" (Ie: A force that would be applied after we know $f$) that does not rely on time, that is: We first compute $r(t)$ and then we take the $x,y$ coordinates of $r(t)$, lets call them $r_x,r_y$ and aplly as follows:

$$F=\left( \frac{Gm_1m_2}{(r_x-a)^2+(r_y-b)^2 } \right) \left(1,1 \right) \textbf{ or } F=Gm_1m_2\left(\frac{1}{(r_x-a)^2},\frac{1}{(r_y-b)^2} \right) \text{?}$$

And in this way $r(t)+F(t)$ would yield the trajectory but it didn't seem to work. Sorry, I am extremely confused.

Notice that I am trying to answer this in terms of a very simplified model. The planet is not orbiting anything it's stopped at a single point $(a,b)$. I noticed that by using the word "planet" may be misleading.

---

## Worship! Play! Play! Worship!

By playing in Geogebra, I tried to guess some random functions that would yield something similar to what I am looking for and I made this:

> [image]

Thinking of the big dot as the planet. I came to:

$$\left( \frac{1}{u}+\sin \left(\frac{1}{u+1}+1\right)-1,\frac{1}{u}+2 \cos
   \left(\frac{1}{u}\right)-1 \right)$$

But this ain't no physics. This is just random guessing to see what it would take to answer this and I guess that - somehow - I'll end up with sums and products of trigonometrical functions.

Comment: your accelerations $a_x\,,a_y$ are function of time not constant!, you have to obtain the EOM's to get $a_x(t)\,,a_y(t)$ then solve the ODE's. your position vector2 are $\vec{R}_i=[x_i(t)\,,y_i(t)]^T$

Comment: Do you really mean two-dimensional space?  Or do you mean a plane in three-dimensional space?  I ask because I wonder if the law of gravity would be different in 2d,

Comment: @Eli Yep. I was using constants for simplicity. But wouldn't it work with constants?

Comment: @garyp I'm not sure. I was thinking as if one were looking to a plane from above, because of this, I thought it could be thought in terms of 2-dimensional space.

Comment: That sounds like motion in a plane in 3d space, like an orbit for example.

Comment: @garyp Yes. But is it too different to consider motion in a plane in 3D space and motion in a plane?

Comment: I don't know.  I might think that in 2d the force would fall of as $1/r$ rather than $1/r^2$.  The latter,  $1/r^2$ I believe to be related to the area of a sphere of radius $r$.. So the 2d case may require the the circumferece of a circle of radius *r&, which falls off linearly with distance.  BTW, SI units in E&M make this explict.  Coulomb's Law is $F=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi r^2}$.   Looked at that way, $\epsilon_0$ is the constant of proportionality, and the force explicitly falls off with the area of a subtended solid angle.  That realization adds some sense to SI units.

Comment: Whoops, at the end I meant "area of a sphere of radius $r$  ($4\pi r^2$)", not subtended angle.  Typed too fast

Comment: You need to solve vector equations, and you are not resolving components correctly. This is actually quite a difficult question even when you have learned the necessary maths. Leave it until you are equipped to deal with it.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis I am actually very curious about it. And I guess I won't be dismayed by the math. It could be anything, people can point me to a book, etc. I also probably "won't be equiped to deal with it" because I am a math major, the (very little) physics I've seen in university didn't seem to cover that.

Comment: @BillyRubina, well you should be using the components of vectors, and it would help to use vector notations. I don't expect you can solve the equations in Cartesian coordinates (I've never seen it done), but you can study the solutions at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit

Comment: @CharlesFrancis Are there other "scenarios" where you have a particle traveling in a space and we want to compute it's trajectory?

Comment: There are multi-body problems - perturbations to orbits due to other planets (Neptune was found by studying perturbations) and modeling of galaxies, which requires N-body simulation. Also of course space craft, which have a rocket boost.

Answer (score 2):

1. In order to obtain position, you should integrate acceleration, not force. So, in particular, the $m$ in your first term shouldn't be there.
2. The integration you performed is only valid for constant acceleration. In order to calculate trajectory in the presence of the gravitational field of a planet, you have to take into account the position-dependent (and possibly time-dependent if the planet itself receives significant back-reaction) acceleration due to gravity. Having taken into account this, you can go on to integrate.
3. However, if you're working in some limit where the gravitational acceleration is constant, e.g., the near Earth approximation where you set the $r$ in the formula of Newtonian gravity to be constant, the integration you performed is valid (modulo my point 1).

Comment: The question has been edited massively. As long as this comment is visible. this answer addresses only a previous version of the question satisfactorily.

Comment: D.C I didn't type what I thought in the first time because I judged what I thought to be a big waste of time.